# Most effective base set-up?

Tags: dont-starve

I already have both the science and alchemy stations, and a stone fire pit. What else should I add or research to make a stable base?

Comment: the more questions i see for this game the more i wanna try it, just gotta get over how much i dislike the graphic style of the game.

Comment: the graphic style definitely grows on you. I didn't like it to start, and even sometimes before I launch the game I kinda don't feel like looking at it, but it definitely suits the mood of the game once you get into it.

Comment: I like the style. It seems Tim Burton-ish to me

Comment: Everyone uses Tim Burton to describe this game. This explains why the main character looks like he's played by Johnny Depp.

Comment: @Paralytic I did the same thing for this game. I thought both the questions for 'Dont Starve' and 'Rust: the game' looked awesome and was deciding between both. I chose this because it had more activity, havent looked back since.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, most of the resources that are renewable and portable you will want nearby. That means using your shovel to dig up bushes, saplings, and tufts of grass and planting them all nearby. Plant trees nearby as well. Ideally these things will be close enough you can get to them at night to have something to do before the sun comes back up, but you don't want to catch them on fire.

You can add farm plots nearby. With farm plots as well as berry bushes, you should have a pretty stable food source even without having to leave your base, or at least without having to leave very often.

You'll want to be able to get manure -- this means either building your base near a beefalo herd (good because they don't ever go crazy and try to kill you, but they wander) or a pigman village (good because you'll always know where to find them, bad because sometimes they go crazy and try and kill you, plus you have to give them stuff in return for manure).

You may want to be within range of a few other resources. Pigman villages you can construct, spider eggs you can move. Either of these, if you want them, should be placed a few screens away so you don't have to fight through the night. Placing your base within a comfortable walk of some tallbird eggs might be a good idea.

I placed my base near a beefalo herd (which is now spreading out pretty well, so this is becoming less effective) as well as a bunch of rabbit holes. I don't have easy access to tallbird eggs, but between farms, bushes, rabbits, and enough manure to keep my farms and bushes going, I pretty much never have to worry about food or basic resources (sticks, wood, grass).

Other than that, just keep things near your base once you can research them -- crock pot, chests, etc. The things you keep closest to your fire should be the things you want to mess with overnight. Hostile (or potentially hostile) things should be kept a few screens away. Everything else can go somewhere in between.

Comment: If you construct the pig house, will pigmen spawn from it or do they have to move in or something? I've only ever seen them once and didn't know if they were hostile so i left them alone. Also is it worth it to just craft straw rolls and skip the night, and do tents act as permanent straw rolls to sleep in?

Comment: Tents are for switching characters, and are consumed after a single use. I don't find skipping the night to be useful, because I usually have things to do in the night, even if it's just to clean my inventory and put manure on crops. Pigmen spawn from their houses, one per house, although they come back after you kill them (the next day, I believe). Pigs are not hostile, but they turn into werepigs under the full moon, and those are hostile. You can feed pigs meat and they will escort you for a day. Monster meat can turn them into werepigs. Feeding seeds or berries causes them to drop manure.

Comment: So if a fullmoon is coming I can just take the house down with a hammer and rebuild it later?

Comment: It is safer and easier to just build the houses far enough away that you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Some of the information addressed in this answer is outdated. Any chance you can update it?

Comment: I haven't kept up with changes to this game since about the time this answer was written. I'd be happy to accept any edits people propose or do anything else to let somebody who has kept up with this game take over the answer here. Otherwise I'd be sorting through a wiki and making guesses as to which changes apply to this answer.

Answer (score 6):

I find it easiest when you make lots of stone walls and surround your base in a grid formation, screen by screen. Try to make several entrances, and put as many Tooth Traps in the hallway as you can. Make the hallway at least fifteen stone walls. You’ll need the following things if you want a “Never-leave-your-base-ever” lifestyle:

- Pigs for help and poop. (Help is only needed if you want to leave your base for a questing adventure, like a cave. Make sure to bring lots of meat or jerky.)
- Traps for rabbits and such (next to rabbit holes).
- Beefalos for fur and horns (not necessary, but nice).
- Put Lightning rods, crock pots, chests, drying racks, a birdcage, and stuff you want to tinker with near your fire.
- Fire pit. Nuff said.
- If possible, get the “King of the Pigs” in one of your “Screen Squares”.
- Berry Bushes, Grass Tufts, Saplings, Trees, and Farms in a screen square.
- Tent(s) (again, not needed, but nice)
- Lots of sanity reducing and refilling items, such as assorted mushrooms (to get Beard-lings and such).

-Get ready for winter, even when one has just ended. Always stockpile food, eat as little as necessary, and when your starving, make some friggin Meatballs.

-If you are starving, eat a cooked meal, not the raw materials. Remember: *Would you rather eat a Small Jerky, or some Meatballs?*

-Some of the best cooked meals are (In my opinion) Fistful of Jam(Put Berries in all the slots.) Meatballs(One meat at the top, and three vegetables under it.) and a Bacon and Eggs, witch is made from one egg at the top, two meat below it, and a stick at the bottom. Keep these foods and others in your base to ward off starvation.

- Get two Heat Stones (one to leave at the fire, one in your pocket, and you can switch out when necessary).
- Make sure you’re never at the pig base at night. **Don’t risk it!**
- And remember, your squares don’t have to be a screen size, or even squares at all.
- The most important rule: **Don’t ever starve!**