# Where should I set up my base?

Tags: dont-starve

So far, I've been pretty unsuccessful with setting up a base. I've been trying to build near replenishing resources (grass, berries, etc) but I guess there's more to it than that because it hasn't really worked out for me. What's the best location to set up a home base? What are the most important things to have nearby? Basically, how can I make the most stable base possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most effective base set-up?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/most-effective-base-set-up)

Comment: I don't think so. I looked at that one. He's asking about making a pre-existing base better with machines. I'm more interested in actual location. Maybe, idk :)

Comment: I feel like the core questions are the same, though: "What do I need for a stable base?" But, I could also be mistaken!

Comment: nbd, we'll just let people decide :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid dying, you need to watch 3 major states:

- Hunger
- Health
- Sanity

Additionally, some security against other ways of dying (mob attacks such as hounds, mactusk, deerclops, ...) can lower your chances of dying too.

The good news is: **everything you need to keep the 3 states up can be moved**: you can plant farms, move berry bushes, grass, twigs, trees, spiders, ...

Resources you'll need to build a base but are not easily movable are **manure** and **stone**. *(Update 22/07/2016: manure is movable if you build pig houses, pigs give manure if you feed them fruits. Turn the pig into a werepig and drop a stack of 40 berries to get 40 manure fast)*

- The easiest ways to find manure are beefalo (which can be moved) or
  pigs (whose houses can be moved or (re)built).
- The easiest ways to get stone are quarries (a stone biome), but those are non-renewable. The only renewable way to get stone is by farming the caves. *(Update 22/07/2016: with meteors, stone biomes are now renewable - but don't build too close or the meteors destroy your base)*

**So you can build your base anywhere you like**. You can move all vital resources anyway, it only costs manure to fertilise the grass and farms, and stone to build your walls. It helps to have those close!

Conclusion: build your base close to

- **caves**, for stone, gold, flint, gems
- **beefalo**, for manure (although you can move beefalo in the long term, starting close gives you a headstart)
- as many different **biomes** as you can find (savanna, grass, rocks, forest, marsh)

Additionally:

- Having **wormholes** near makes the base more interesting, since travels to other biomes are shortened, and you have an escape hatch.
- Having a **respawn** near (touchstone, meat effigy) makes for a good base, too, since after you respawn, you can reach your base fast (before you die again)
- Having **multiple bases** can make the difference between life and death when you get chased out of your base during winter/nighttime or when you respawn. Build a second base at your touch stones, in the caves, in the ruins...

A good example of a base in my latest game, day 3:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have the best luck building my base near a beefalo herd.  This supplies you with several important resources:

- **Manure** - you can build farms with it, fertilize them with it for quick crops, and burn it for fuel
- **Beefalo Wool** - you can burn it for fuel, and you can use it as an ingredient in some winter clothing
- **Beefalo Horn** - if a beefalo dies (or you kill one), you can get one of these, which lets you create a Beefalo Hat, the warmest hat in the game
- **Grass** - perhaps the most constant resource you'll need, and obtainable because beefalo tend to inhabit grasslands
- **Rabbits** - important for food in the winter, when crops don't grow.  You can set traps right over their holes

Set up near the beefalo, and you'll have food and fuel year-round.  Beefalo are also helpful backup fighters against hounds, and they're great for killing koalefants when they're in heat.

If you can't find a good-sized herd of beefalo, another good option is near a pig village.  This gets you manure (from feeding plants to the pigs), and gold (from the pig king, in exchange for meat and other objects).  I find getting manure from the pigs more labor-intensive than getting it from beefalo, though.

**Update for Wigfrid**

If you have the Reign of Giants DLC, things are a bit different.  Wigfrid in particular takes some special handling because she won't eat vegetables (by themselves).  She'll only eat meat, meat dishes, and eggs.

For Wigfrid, my ideal location is a **pig village** near some **spider dens**.  This allows several sources of food:

- **Monster Meat** from the spiders.  This can be combined with non-twig filler in a crockpot to produce **Meatballs**, one serving of which restores nearly a day's worth of hunger.
- **Meat** from the pigs.  If you feed four monster meat to a pig, he becomes a werepig.  Killing the werepig yields two meats and one pigskin.  The meat can be eaten on its own or combined in the crockpot to make meatballs or other items.
- You can also feed cooked monster meat (from the spiders) to a bird in a birdcage to make eggs, which you can trade to the pig king for gold.

This is a great setting year-round, because pigs and spiders are active during all four seasons.